# Выделить текст при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно выделить текст внутри `div`-элемента при клике на него? В `jQuery` нет стандартного метода для такого действия?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Существует спецификация ([Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Selection)), описывающая как JavaScript код может взаимодействовать с выделением текста на странице.

Не вдаваясь в детали покажу, как с помощью этого API выделить содержимое `<div>` при клике без использования jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('select-target').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var r = document.createRange();
    r.selectNode(this);
    document.getSelection().addRange(r);
});
```

Вот [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuf8ven6/3/) с примером.

**Замечание:**

Если вам нужно написать максимально кроссбраузерный код, то можно использовать библиотеки, оборачивающие Selection API, например, [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
 function selectText(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) { // IE
   var range = document.body.createTextRange();
   range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
   range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
   var range = document.createRange();
   range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
   window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  }
 }
</script>

<div id="example" onclick="selectText('example')">Hello This div content have to be select.</div>
```